# Travis CI build fails because it can't find the secret key file stored in my local home directory. How to handle this?

Tags: file, properties, travis-ci, secret-key

I can't put the secret key file in the project folder. How can I handle this scenario?

My properties file has database password which is encrypted. My project uses it to connect to embedded H2 database.

Is there any other encryption method that I can use?

Edit:

Language: Java

Scenario --> I have a .secret file that has a private key

Now I have a properties file that has a property: db.password=encryptedPassword

When connecting to DB in my unit tests, I need the secret key file to be able to decrypt the password. This works fine in my local as the .secret file is in my user.home directory.

But when the build runs in Travis CI it fails because it can't find the .secret file.

Comment: Can you share programming language and technology you’re using?

Comment: @EleazarEnrique - Added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must get the private key in a different way for Unit Tests purposes.

> TravisCI allows to configure Environment variables, so you can store the private key into a Environment variable, i.e `PRIVATE_KEY=Content_of_Private_key`

**Take a look at this image from Travis console:**

[image]

**In your code you can get that content as follow:**

```
System.getenv().get("PRIVATE_KEY"); //This call returns the content you need for decrypt your password.
```

Like I said, this behavior should be a good approach for your Unit tests.

**Hope it helps!**

Comment: This is a pretty good idea in my opinion as well. I will change my code to get the value/path of secret key at run time. Will try this! Thanks.

In the meantime what I have done is to setup a test database solely for unit test purpose.